# Iplementing Jain SIP in Android

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to make an android app using Jain SIP. I already read the basic tutorial for SIP and now I'm looking for a tutorial how to implement jain sip in android. I search but I didn't saw anything how to implement it on android. So I'm asking to anyone who knows a link of tutorial how to implement jain sip in android, just a simple example how to use it on androidh.

Any thoughts will be highly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both are SIP client APIs there are differences in the two, implementing JAIN SIP on Android SIP APIs will be difficult or at best incomplete because JAIN SIP is a much lower level API.

For example Android SIP APIs do not expose the SIP Stack as you would expect in JAIN SIP, you cannot access SIP transactions in Android etc.

With Android API you can create a manage a SIP client easily and that is what it is ideally suited for without going to low level SIP protocol tinkering.

If you want to implement JAIN SIP API layer in Android you may have to write or use your own SIP stack (like the NIST JAIN client).

Answer (score 3):

The stock native android sip stack is built on top of JAIN SIP but it does not have all functionality, there is no support for IM, presence and video calls right now. Google forked SIP Stack and never really updated the SIP API that is shipped by default and used the same package names as the original JAIN SIP project. This proved to be a major hassle to developers that wanted to add SIP capabilities worldwide as they couldn’t use JAIN SIP out of the box.

An opensource implementation of the Android JAIN SIP stack can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/jain-sip/

It is a java based SIP stack which allows you to integrate the sip stack seamlessly in your android application without the hassle of NDK.

A Complete SIP Stack
JAIN SIP is a full implementation of the RFC 3261 Specification and as well as support for several SIP RFCs.

What is the issue using the existing JAIN SIP stack?

If you have tried to use the existing JAIN SIP in any android application you might have run into package name conflicts, these conflicts are resolved now and the stack is ready to be used in android.

The full blog post with example code and Android APK is available here:
http://www.telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/